# Emacs - fixed tab width

Tags: emacs

I'm editing a text-document styled on its own way of which Emacs doesn't recognize the markup, and opens it in fundamental-mode. Tab indentation is the most problematic behaviour.

Can I fix tab width with a runtime command, only for the current session?

Particularly I'd avoid any permanent in-file configuration.

Comment: Also, when you say you wish to avoid in-file configuration, do you only mean the document file you are editing, or does that include your own Emacs configuration as well? (the latter could be made to automatically configure behaviour for a specified file without changing the default behaviour).

Comment: That will change the *displayed width* of tabs, but do note that it has no bearing on what happens when you type a tab. Fundamental mode uses `indent-relative` which moves point to align with the contents of the previous line, and uses the `tab-stop-list` variable otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `M-x set-variable` to set variables at runtime and only for that buffer and session, ideally you can set the offset variable (for instance in c-common-mode it's c-basic-offset) and you can change this value to the desired tab width (although I recommend you use spaces instead of tabs for consistency as tab characters `\t` are usually 8 spaces wide.